# How to run a VBA Macro on Linux machine?

Tags: linux, vba

I Have a VBA code that i want to run on a linux machine.

This VBA code actually check for cosmetic error in python scripts. We create our scripts on Linux machines and then for review we copy it on windows machine just to run vba code.

If anyone can help me to run the same code on linux machine then it would be of great help.

Answer (score 0):

VBA is Visual Basic for Applications (runs inside Word, Excel, etc).

VB(Visual Basic) is a native windows application.

All of them can usually run on Linux by using wine. Make sure to install wine using(assuming you are using a Debian-based distro):

```
 apt-get install wine
```

Comment: Can you please rephrase your answer and correct your typos? Thank you.

Comment: After installing WINE, Shall i be able to run the same vb code on linux machine or i need to change my code ?

Comment: No you have install VBA into wine  https://appdb.winehq.org/appview.php?iVersionId=1325