# Opening and viewing an excel macro in Ubuntu or R

Tags: r, excel, ubuntu-16.04, vba

I have been passed on an Excel macro along with a sample dataset upon which the macro runs, and I need to replicate and add upon the processing steps that it carries out in R. I'm running Ubuntu on my machine and I have no experience with Windows nor Excel. Is it possible to open up the macro in Ubuntu or in R and find out what it is doing? If so does anyone know how? Thanks!

Comment: use wine? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29028381/how-to-run-a-vba-macro-on-linux-machine

Comment: @dv3 Thanks but wouldn't wine also require a windows OS?

Comment: don't think so - but please refer to the wiki... SO is probably the wrong place for such a question

Answer (score 0):

I just the the following code and it works fine.

```
library(RDCOMClient)

# Open a specific workbook in Excel:
xlApp <- COMCreate("Excel.Application")
xlWbk <- xlApp$Workbooks()$Open("C:\\Users\\Excel\\Desktop\\Condo.xls")

# this line of code might be necessary if you want to see your spreadsheet:
xlApp[['Visible']] <- TRUE 

# Run the macro called "MyMacro":
xlApp$Run("MyMacro")

# Close the workbook and quit the app:
xlWbk$Close(FALSE)
xlApp$Quit()

# Release resources:
rm(xlWbk, xlApp)
gc()
```

Clearly, you run it from R.  Also, see the link below to auto-fire a Macro in Excel when a workbook opens.

https://analysistabs.com/excel-vba/run-macro-automatically-opening-workbook/

```
'The following Macro sits in the 'ThisWorkbook' module.
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
  Msgbox "Welcome to ANALYSIS TABS"
End Sub
```